# Calculate the distance from Plickford to Murbell

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, angle

Attached is my question. Please provide an explanation for how I could calculate the distance from Plickford to Murbell.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT :

$\angle{MBP}=57^\circ+(180^\circ-155^\circ)=82^\circ$.

Now use the [law of cosines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines).